# How to inject custom SSLSocketFactory into Azure Java SDK

Tags: java, azure, ssl, active-directory, sslsocketfactory

Is there a way I can override the `SSLSocketFactory` used by default by Azure HTTPConnection and use my own custom `SSLSocketFactory`? I need this because the system I use communicates with different servers using different SSLContexts and I can't use the default SSLSocketFactory.

I have raised [an issue on the AD library for java on github](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java/issues/54) regarding the same, but if there is a way I can override it, that would be better before a code fix is done.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, Azure SDK for Java used the `SSLContext` and `SSLSocketFactory` which is in package `javax.net.ssl`

```
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
```

I think you can use `sslContext.getInstance(*yourparamters*)` for different `SSLContext` if I am understanding rightly. Base on my experience, we can use this method to returns a `SSLContext` object that implements the specified secure socket protocol. 
For example, if you use `SSLV3`, you can code as following:

```
SSLContext context=SSLContext.getInstance("SSLv3");
```

Actually, you also use the same method to set the `TLS` and `SSL`.
I suggest you can refer to [samples about SSLSocketFactory](http://www.javased.com/?api=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory)

---

【UPDATE】

> This is how I would add an SSL context for a generic SSLSocketFactory.
>   I want to know to do this for the Azure java SDK.

If I am understanding, it seems that you want to get the different SocketFactroy for different servers. On this scenario, I suggest you can create a socketfactory management class to manage all of your socketfactory. Please see this simple code:

```
public class SSLScoketFactoryManage {

    public static SSLSocketFactory getSSLSocketFactory(String keyStoreName, String password) throws UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, IOException {
        KeyStore ks= getKeyStore(keyStoreName, password);
        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        keyManagerFactory.init(ks, password.toCharArray());

          SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
          context.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), null, new SecureRandom());

          return context.getSocketFactory();
    }


    }
```

you can use this method in different sockets as following :

```
SSLSocketFactory sslFactory = getSSLSocketFactory(keyStore, keyStorePassword);
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setSSLSocketFactory(sslFactory);
```

Any concerns, please let me known.

Comment: This is how I would add an SSL context for a generic SSLSocketFactory. I want to know to do this for the Azure java SDK.

Comment: I update my reply, please refer to it. If I an misunderstanding, please let me know

Comment: I think the question didn't clarify: I am using the adal4j library that Microsoft provides to authenticate from the AD server, I am not writing my own SDK. [This is the sample I am using to authenticate](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java/blob/master/src/samples/public-client-app-sample/src/main/java/PublicClient.java). Please let me know if the question is still unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I think Will's answer is correct. The SSLSocketFactory is generic class and is not specific to Azure. You can use the above method in your own code. Based on your servers you can create different SSLSocketFactory objects. I don't see any reason for Azure SDK for Java to expose the SSLSocketFactory it is using. And if it does, then it is specific to Azure http communication and I dont think you would be able to use it for other servers. 
Can you please clarify your question more? Also, I would recommend you to add "adal" to your tags so that Adal team can take a look at it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adal